# Won't abalone be unchewable and stony if you steam for 6 hours?

Tags: cooking-time, seafood

The last time I went to a seafood restaurant in Sai Kung, we bought fresh abalone from store on ground floor, then took it ourselves to restaurant. Restaurant cooked them in 25 mins, and abalone was tender.

On the other hand, [a blogger](http://www.diarygrowingboy.com/2020/06/mitsuboshi-mae.html) describes a dish made with abalone that was steamed for a very long time.

> The first ingredient to come out was a pair of abalone from Australia which have been steamed with *sake* **for 6 hours**.

So what’s the difference between cooking the abalone very quickly and very long - and what about the times I between, e.g. cooking the abalone for an hour?

Comment: It might be a typo in the blog, or a misunderstanding between the blog writer and the chef at the restaurant.

Comment: It might be like octopus, where you either cook it very quickly, or very slowly ... as times in between can end up being rubbery.

Comment: And the blogger nowhere said that the abalone was tender.

Comment: I'd suggest that you look up slow-cooking. It is commonly used to deal with tough cuts of meat; I see no reason it wouldn't work with abalone.